# Primary Disk vs Swap Disk

Tags: google-compute-engine, vps

I am using Google Compute Engine with 90GB of SSD. As my site is growing, cost has also shooted up. I tried shifting to https://www.vpb.com but they gave me

30GB Primary Disk and 60GB Swap Disk (Both are SSDs as they said).

The proposed cost has also decreased to 50%. My RAM is just 8GB.

Is above configuration different from 90GB SSD disk in Google Compute Engine?

Comment: Why do you need so much disk space? could you use Cloudstorage buckets instead of disk? or store items in the Datastore/CloudSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is above configuration different from 90GB SSD disk in Google Compute Engine?

Yes. Google Compute Engine is a full-featured IaaS platform where you can create VMs with the disks (and sizes) you need. The Persistent Disk is designed to be reliable, allows for easy snapshots, and you can also resize them while the VM is running.

This other server might be giving you 2 different disks for their VM or dedicated machine and you will have to design your site to use them both. Swap disks are really only meant for temporary work and it's strange to see them being offered separately like that. They also might be attached to the machine rather than reliable storage like GCP's persistent disks.

If 90GB isn't enough on your GCP VM, how will 30+60 be enough in this other machine? Are you uploading large media files? You might be better served by using Cloud Storage or S3 for those files.

Comment: I have 200k+ images on my server. These images occupy 67GB in my server. I cannot roll back to 67GB because in GCE we cannot decrease size of SSDs. These images are served by Jetpack's photon CDN.

My biggest motivation to move is that it will cut down cost by more than 50%.

Thanks a lot for your feedback on disks - I will ask them for more details.

Comment: @RohitManglik I would recommend using Google Cloud Storage or S3 or any other object storage system which are designed for storing files (objects) like these. You can easily use CDNs with object storage as well. This means your image files will be reliably stored and available from anywhere, even without a server. Then you can just run a small server to run the website code itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclosure: I am a product manager on Google Cloud Platform (but not Google Compute Engine or Persistent Disk specifically).*

> 30GB Primary Disk and 60GB Swap Disk (Both are SSDs as they said).
>
> The proposed cost has also decreased to 50%. My RAM is just 8GB.
>
> Is above configuration different from 90GB SSD disk in Google Compute Engine?

Note that a "disk in a machine" is very different from a Google Compute Engine persistent disk:

- A "disk in a machine" is exactly that: a single physical device. If it fails, you are expected to have made a backup of it prior to failure. How you make the backup is up to you.
- A [Google Compute Engine persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs) is a replicated disk, so a single disk failure will not cause you to lose data. You *can* make backups (snapshots) of your persistent disk, and it's highly recommended, and you can use Google Cloud Storage for this purpose, but it's typically used for protecting against application bugs, not persistent disk durability.

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41374548/3618671) says, GCE persistent disk also has a [live resize capability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) so that you can easily increase the size of it if needed.

Google Cloud Platform has many more services besides just VMs: databases, key-value storage, object/blob storage, etc. so there's more to consider when making your decision.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above - there are 2 important things to understand:

- SWAP + disk is not the same as a big disk. SWAP is basically cheap RAM, in case you're running low on it. If you have 60+GB of static data on your VM, 30GB disk is more than twice as small as your minimum.
- Using Disk for storing static data (e.g. images may be served from storage instances, that are way cheaper).